# What Lokas did Arjuna attain after death?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna

In Svargārohaṇa parva, I heard that Yudhiṣṭhira sees Arjuna with Kṛṣṇa but later, the end of the Mahābhārata characters is explained. Karṇa merges into Sūrya, Kṛṣṇa merges in to Viṣṇu and Yudhiṣṭhira into Yama. My question is, what happened to Arjuna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He attained Viṣṇu Loka and was with Kṛṣṇa.

> He beheld Govinda endued with his Brahma-form. It resembled that form of his which had been seen before and which, therefore, helped the recognition. Blazing forth in that form of his, he was adorned with celestial weapons, such as the terrible discus and others in their respective embodied forms. **He was being adored by the heroic Phālguṇa, who also was endued with a blazing effulgence.** The son of Kunti beheld the slayer of Madhu also in his own form. **Those two foremost of Beings, adored by all the gods, beholding Yudhiṣṭhira, received him with proper honours.**

[From Section 4 Svargārohaṇika Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m18/m18004.htm).

Comment: During suspension period you should not create a new account. If you do so Mods will easily find that out and the ban on your original account will be extended. Just wait for the ban period to end and then you can resume posting with your original account (Fun Life).

Comment: Fun life if you creatre a false account create it ina different name.